# How to install Solarized theme?

Tags: terminal

I'm having trouble making my terminal look exactly like the SOLARIZED theme. http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized

I downloaded the file and made it default on my terminal os x but it doesn't show red/yellow/blue and all the beautiful colors just a plain solarized theme with no color.

I'm I doing something? do I need to modify my .bash_profile file some how to get the colors to show?